# In Xamarin Forms why does my label's text binding break in a StackLayout in iOS?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to put a label in a StackLayout, but as soon as I do, the text binding stops working and the entire control doesn't show (I know because it has a red background when it works).

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="{Binding MyObject.MyObjectsStringProperty}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" BackgroundColor="Red" />
    <Other control with working binding/>
</StackLayout>
```

Why does `Text="{Binding Object.ObjectStringProperty}"` not work? I'm only seeing this behaviour in iOS, and not Android, so I'm thinking it might be a bug unless I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: You might be missing something obvious, because that's a basic common feature. I'm pretty sure you're doing something wrong. What's your `BindingContext` ?

Comment: Is your property actually named "Object"? What if you rename it to something that isn't the same name as a system type?

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of name for my simplified code, see edit

Comment: @Greggz, I don't have a BindingContext set in the xaml, I don't think. I wasn't aware that I needed one seeing as the label just worked in the first place, before I tried adding it to this stacklayout?

Comment: @Chucky I'll give you an example on how it should be done.

Comment: @Chucky Please check my answer and make your questions there

Answer (score 0):

So I couldn't really understand how you were implementing it, but this is how it's mostly done and well done.

You need to establish first a `BindingContext` to your `Page` like this. Using MVVM, every Page has it's own ViewModel. A ViewModel has Properties that can be referenced in the XAML code trough Binding tecnhiques.

```
public MyPage {
    BindingContext = new MyPageViewModel();
}

public class PageViewModel {

    public ObjectStringProperty = "Example";
}

<StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Text="{Binding ObjectStringProperty}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="12" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" BackgroundColor="Red" />
    <Other control with working binding/>
</StackLayout>
```